# Why am I getting an empty string when reading user input?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to do something similar to this.

```
#!/bin/bash
readonly bkp_path="x01/trdprod"
bkp_location=" "
bkp_dir=" "

function crt_bkp_dir(){
    bkp_dir=$(whiptail --title "Test" --inputbox "Insert backup directory name" 10 100\
--ok-button "Create" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    bkp_location="$bkp_path/$bkp_dir"
}

function main(){
    crt_bkp_dir
    echo $bkp_location
}

main
```

I need to get the output `x01/trdprod/test`. Instead I get an empty output. Can someone tell me what did I do wrong and how to do it right?

--- Update----
I updated my initial question. I use 'whiptail' program to show dialog boxes and to get user inputs.
When I echo $bkp_location inside the crt_bkp_dir function I get the desired out put. but not inside main function.

Comment: if I use `read bkp_dir` (per my answer), or `bkp_dir=test`, then the `main() / echo $bkp_location` generates `x01/trdprod/test`; setting aside whatever code you're working on in your env, if you cut-n-paste this block of code (above) into a file, `chmod 700` the file, and then exec the file ... you still don't get the desired output? how are you calling the script/file?

Comment: after inserting a space between the `100` and the backslash I cut-n-pasted your entire script (above) into a file (`whip.bash`) in my `Ubuntu 22.04/bash` env, `chmod 700 whip.bash`, then executed the script (`./whip.bash`) ... `whiptail` opened a window, I entered `test` and hit enter/return, and `x01/trdprod/test` was displayed in the terminal; at this point the script works as expected (ie, I'm unable to reproduce your issue); is this code (above) an *exact* copy of what you're running in your env?

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Comment: Aside from the issues that shellcheck will tell you about, it is impossible for the script in your question to produce empty output. You must be doing something else you haven't shown us yet. Add `set -x` to the top of your script to help you debug it then post a new question with a [mcve] if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`bkp_dir=$(read user_input)` sets variable `bkp_dir` to the *output* of `read user_input`, which is typically nothing (ie, `bkp_dir` ends up set to a blank).

Try the following:

```
# replace this:

bkp_dir=$(read user_input)

# with this:

read bkp_dir
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, my requirement is little diferent. I have updated my question accordingly. Any insight on that?